# Recursive practice problem help: remembers last function call's dictionary

Tags: python, recursion

EDIT: I read the linked posts in comments, but I still don't understand what I can do to my code to change it. I get *why* it happens now in terms of it using the same object, but which part can I change so that it won't give me an error while resetting dictOut to an empty dictionary every time it's called?

---

My results remember the dictOut values that were in the previous function call.

For example, calling
`lengthDict(["Alex", "Josh", "Fareeda", "Parul"])` gives:

-->  `{'Parul': 3, 'Fareeda': 3, 'Josh': 3, 'Alex': 2}`,

but then calling `lengthDict(["Michael", "Craig", "Shane"])` after that returns:

--> `{'Parul': 3, 'Fareeda': 3, 'Josh': 3, 'Alex': 2, 'Michael': 4, 'Craig': 3, 'Shane': 3}`

Here is my code:

```
"""
Function Name: lengthDict()
Parameters: list of names (list)
Returns: dictionary mapping names to length (dict)
"""
def lengthDict(namesList, dictOut = {}, count = 0):
    if len(namesList) == 0:
        return dictOut
    consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
    indX = 0
    while indX in range(len(namesList[0])):
        if namesList[0][indX].lower() in consonants:
            count += 1
        indX += 1
    dictOut[namesList[0]] = (count)
    return lengthDict(namesList[1:])
```

Comment: Every call to `lengthDict` without an explicit second argument uses the *same* object for `dictOut`.

Comment: The short explanation is that `dictOut = {}` is only executed _once_, when the function is defined, and changes made to it are retained between calls.  You do _not_ get a new copy of `dictOut` each time the function is called.  See the link at the top for more details.

Comment: To fix this, change your function header to say `dictOut = None`, and then have the first line be `if dictOut is None:` / `dictOut = {}`.

Comment: That didn't work, it always return empty dict :(